# Download the file using Camel ConsumerTemplate multiple times

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse

I am trying to download the same file multiple times using **Camel** **ConsumerTemplate**. It's not getting downloaded multiple times, but I am getting it done while using **camel route**.
I want to **download the file using ConsumerTemplate multiple times**.
 Here is the code that I am trying with ConsumerTemplate:

```
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.ConsumerTemplate;
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Processor;

    public class DynamicConsumer implements Processor {

        @Override
        public void process(Exchange inExchange) throws Exception {
            CamelContext camelContext = inExchange.getContext();
            ConsumerTemplate consumerTemplate = camelContext.createConsumerTemplate();
            String resource = "sftp://tester@localhost:22/myfiles?password=password&noop=true&idempotent=false&readLockMarkerFile=false&readLock=none&filter=#myFileFilter";
            consumerTemplate.start();
            Exchange resourceExchange = consumerTemplate.receive(resource,20000);
            consumerTemplate.stop();
            if(resourceExchange != null) {
                inExchange.getOut().setBody(resourceExchange.getIn().getBody());
                inExchange.getProperties().putAll(resourceExchange.getProperties());
                inExchange.getOut().getHeaders().putAll(resourceExchange.getIn().getHeaders());
            } else {
                inExchange.getOut().setBody(null);
            }
        }
    }
```

This dynamic consumer is getting called from the camel routes multiple times. So, each time, I expect to download the file present in given location. But it is not happening.

Here the code that I tried with camel route.

```
<from uri="sftp://tester@localhost:22/myfiles?password=password&amp;noop=true&amp;idempotent=false&amp;readLockMarkerFile=false&amp;readLock=none&amp;filter=#myFileFilter"/>
```

Comment: Do you have an exchange property with the `sftp://tester@localhost:22/myfiles?password=password&noop=true&idempotent=false&readLockMarkerFile=false&readLock=none&filter=#myFileFilter"` name/key?

Comment: @mgyongyosi Sorry, I made a mistake while simplifying the code. It is actually, taking another assigned property from camel  exchange. Corrected it now.

Comment: Are you sure that the required file is on the location? Can you post your route? Also, your processor is working like a Content Enricher, why don't you use Camel's `pollEnrich(uri)` DSL function?  (http://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html)

Comment: @mgyongyosi Required file is available in the location and it is getting downloaded for the first time. I want to trigger the job on scheduled intervals. There are multiple locations from which I want to download the data. I'm not using pollRich due to lack of support for dynamic URI(till version 2.16). I'm bound to version 2.15.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the documentation states you should call the ConsumerTemplate's –`doneUoW(Exchange)` function:

> If you have used any of the receive methods which returns a Exchange
>   type then you need to invoke this method when you are done using the
>   returned Exchange.
>
> -- [ConsumerTemplate documentation](https://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/ConsumerTemplate.html#doneUoW(org.apache.camel.Exchange))

Try to add the following before `consumerTemplate.stop()`:

```
consumerTemplate.doneUoW(resourceExchange);
```